# Add FrameLayout At The bottom Of Any Activity Programmatically

Tags: android, layout, android-activity

How can I find the root view of an activity, then add a framelayout at the bottom? On the contrary, code below add to the top, but can't to its bottom.

```
    FrameLayout aLayout = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
    aLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    ImageView image = new ImageView(getActivity());
    image.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.alayer_0);
    adLayout.addView(image);

    ViewGroup content = (ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    content.addView(aLayout);
```

Comment: Thank you all, But I want add it programmatically and in any activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*android.R.id.content* is a `FrameLayout`. So you cannot align child view to bottom.

What you can do is add a `RelativeLayout` to *android.R.id.content* with `FILL_PARENT` for height and width.

You can now add your `FrameLayout` to the `RelativeLayout` with `ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM`.

Comment: Will this bottom footer overlay the activity's content?

Comment: Yes since the Parent view is FrameLayout it should overlay the activity's content.

Answer (score 3):

Might be one solution is that you should use by xml ,in xml first take one relative layout and than inside that relative layout take your frame layout and set property of frame layout as-

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

so your frame layout will be shown on the bottom of screen.Hope it will work perfectly for you.

Answer (score 1):

Assign some `id` to your Root layout(Main layout of your XML)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear_root"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

Activity class, Map the Root layout

```
LinearLayout mRootLayout;

mRootLayout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_root);

mRootLayout.add(yourFrameLayout);// this will add your FrameLayout at the last
```

**Update**: To get the Root Layout of any Activity then you can use [**getRootView**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getRootView%28%29)

or `getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)`

Comment: Thank you, But I want add it programmatically.

Comment: the one I answered is programmatically itself.

Comment: As Vivek below said, android.R.id.content is a FrameLayout. So I added it at the top of activity, but not the bottom. thx all the same.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you want to add a footer. Start your xml with framelayout  and then include your footer in a linear or relative layout and give android:layout_gravity="bottom". This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can also add a margin around your FrameLayout. No need for an additional RelativeLayout.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = MyActivity.this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(0, metrics.heightPixels - 20, 0, 0);
myFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

This will position the FrameLayout 20 pixels from the bottom of the screen.